# Mounting Windows 7 host folder into VirtualBox guest Ubuntu 12.04 directory

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

I know this is not strictly a question about programming but I need to mount the shared folder in order to continue my coding.

I've got a Windows 7 OS with a guest Ubuntu 12.04 OS inside VirtualBox.

I have been trying to mount a shared folder created in VirtualBox. The virtual folder is basically the `C:\` file system on Windows 7. In VirtualBox the shared folder appears as:

Folder Path: `C:\`

Folder Name: Windows7

```
# sudo mount -t vboxsf Windows7 /windows7
```

But the VirtualBox shared folder filesystem type is not recognized by the "mount" command. The error I get is:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'vboxsf'
```

Conversely, if I try it from the DOS prompt I also get an error after a long pause:

```
> net use x: \\vboxsvr\Windows7
```

(the error which is in my locale basically says:
`it is impossible to find the network path`).

So, what should I do. I've been able to do this operation in the past a previous version of Ubuntu and VirtualBox by installing something called "guest additions".

Could someone please shed some light on how to solve this problem?

---

OK, since nobody answered my post I've done some research and the way to get
it to work (so that the "Virtual Box Shared Folder" type to -t is recognized,
is to install dynamic kernel module support, reboot Linux, and install the
guest addition via the supplied package as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo /sbin/reboot
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-x11
sudo mount -t vboxsf Windows7 /windows7
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure that VBoxLinuxAdditions.run are completed without errors.
After install reboot your virtual machine so the kernel load the modules of virtualbox.

Normally you should be able to mount the folder.

See here
http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2008/04/09/virtualbox-access-windows-host-shared-folders-from-ubuntu-guest/

Comment: Does it matter what kind of Network mode is being used. It worked on bridged. But not on NAT / Nat Network